# show file name instead of No file selected at update time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When I want to update upload image in my form. I can't display previous value.
I fetch file name successfully from database.
How to show file name in file type attribute in php at the update time
Here, I had try to assign value but at validation time this value is taken as null value.

```
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" value="<?= $row->image ?>" required;>
```

can we display another string instead of 'No file selected' in file type

Comment: You can't set value for file inputs for security reasons.

Comment: You may like  to go through this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html).

Comment: I validate this file with ajax validation and here i got error message. If we can't set value then how to validate file at update time?

Comment: show it without file input

Answer (score 3):

You can't set the value of a file element by code for security reasons. Just put a text next to it showing the current uploaded file, and change the label of the file element to something like "Upload new image"